# Non normalisability implies uncertainty principle?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, normalization

The wave function $\psi(x,t)$ for a free particle assuming that the position and momentum is well defined, can be solved from the schroedinger equation, $$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi+V\psi=\hat{E}\psi$$
And that wave function is $$\psi(x,t)=Ae^{i(kx−\omega{t})}$$
and also we know that this wavefunction is not normalisable. Thus we conclude that this particle has no well defined momentum (and hence energy).
But uncertainty principle says the same thing. That is, particle has no well defined momentum and position. Now, my question is that is these two concepts are same? That is, non-normalisability implies uncertainty principle? or is there a different conceptual explannation about the non normalisability of the wavefunction? I think a big mistake happened to me in understanding both these concepts. pls help

Comment: You say *particle has no well defined momentum* but this is not true. The momentum is precisely known. This fits with the uncertainty principle because the position is completely unknown i.e. $\Delta p = 0$ and $\Delta x = \infty$.

Comment: See also [Why does a plane wave leave the position of the particle unspecified?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169718/why-does-a-plane-wave-leave-the-position-of-the-particle-unspecified)